# How to achieve the user defined target in Rajawali-Vufoira android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, rajawali

I am currently using Rajawali sdk(https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliVuforia) for developing my android augmented reality application. Here i am able to change the targets like Frame marker,Image targets and its working perfectly. But i would like to implement the user defined target in  my application. Is there any options or features available in rajawali to implement the user defined targets.
*Thanks for helping*

Answer (score 1):

## Using the Image class

- Register for the desired image format using the `CameraDevice.SetFrameFormat` method:
  `CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888, true);`
- Call this method after QCARBehaviour has a chance to run its `Start` method.
- Use the Unity script-ordering feature, or do this once in an `Update` callback.
- Retrieve the image using the `CameraDevice.GetCameraImage` method.
- Take this action from the `ITrackerEventHandler.OnTrackablesUpdated` callback. That way you can ensure that you retrieve the latest camera image that matches the current frame.

Always make sure that the camera image is not null, since it can take a few frames for the image to become available after registering for an image format.

Here is the full script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class CameraImageAccess : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Image.PIXEL_FORMAT m_PixelFormat = Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB888;
    private bool m_RegisteredFormat = false;
    private bool m_LogInfo = true;
    void Start()
    {
        QCARBehaviour qcarBehaviour = (QCARBehaviour) FindObjectOfType(typeof(QCARBehaviour));
        if (qcarBehaviour)
        {
            qcarBehaviour.RegisterTrackablesUpdatedCallback(OnTrackablesUpdated);
        }
    }
    public void OnTrackablesUpdated()
    {
        if (!m_RegisteredFormat)
        {
            CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(m_PixelFormat, true);
            m_RegisteredFormat = true;
        }
        if (m_LogInfo)
        {
            CameraDevice cam = CameraDevice.Instance;
            Image image = cam.GetCameraImage(m_PixelFormat);
            if (image == null)
            {
                Debug.Log(m_PixelFormat + " image is not available yet");
            }
            else
            {
                string s = m_PixelFormat + " image: \n";
                s += "  size: " + image.Width + "x" + image.Height + "\n";
                s += "  bufferSize: " + image.BufferWidth + "x" + image.BufferHeight + "\n";
                s += "  stride: " + image.Stride;
                Debug.Log(s);
                m_LogInfo = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I couldnt find the image class where it is located?. Could you tell me

Comment: It's in `UnityEngine.UI`

Comment: Unity contains these files. If you're going to use Rajwali code it's a similar procedure. You need to use the Android API on top of which you're going to be using Rajwali. So from Android API, get the Camera class, and make the changes needed.

Comment: Link for reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html

Comment: in which format target image i have to use?.in rajawali .dat file is used

Comment: i am using user defined image (Run time capture) . in run time i cant convert to .dat or .xml